# autohotkey wildcard read loop

Tags: wildcard, autohotkey

I want one script to command several computers to break up a highly distributable workload. In order to distribute the workload I put half of the task labels in one file, and half of the tasks in another file that i distribute to the computers with google drive (which is why i need different file names).  So C:\googledrive\task1.txt and C:\googledrive\task2.txt

The autohotkey command looks like:

```
loop, read, c:\googledrive\task*.txt
```

But instead of reading task1.txt, it appears to try to read "task*.txt" as a literal file name, fails, and ends the loop.

Ideas?  Thanks.

OK, tried ensuring everything was running with administrator rights (they are) and ensured that the files exist (they do) and no typos in the file path (everything good there).  Still wont actually read the file.

There is one bit that I didn't include in the original post part of the file name is actually a variable, so the loop command is actually like:

```
 loop, read, c:\googledrive\%task%*.txt
```

I just figured that bit was inconsequential.

If i save a different script for each computer, i can go ahead and replace the wildcard with the actual bit, and it works.

so... Im just going to name each file with the computer's name in the file, and change the command to:

```
loop, read, c:\googledrive\%task%%A_ComputerName%.txt
```

Comment: Works on my computer, either the file does not exist, or the script wasn't ran with administrator rights and has to access folder that requires admin access.

Comment: Thanks, ill try investigating the folder privileges and see if that solves it.

Comment: No idea why it wouldn't work for me with the wild card, but using the computer name variable in the file name solved the problem, and actually simplifies the whole process by a step or two.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that's an interesting approach to have the script load up every file name in a directory.  I've got this one solved for now, but i will keep that in mind for future efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I do it this way....

```
Loop, C:\Temp\Source\*.txt ; Lists the next file as A_LoopFileName
{
    Loop, read, C:\Temp\Source\%A_LoopFileName% ; process current file
    {
        IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, abc
        {
        .......
        }
    }
}
```